# invalid assignment left-hand side using $this

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to resize a series of images as the browser width decreases.  The following code works fine, but of course as the browser increases, the img being passed cannot be resize cropped to a larger size.

```
$('#image img').each(function() {
      $($(this)).resizecrop({
      width:width,
      height:height,
      vertical:"top"
    });  
});
```

With this code, I'm trying to pass through the original image, resize crop it, and then swap it for the smaller image.  I'm getting an error, assigning the new image to $(this) (invalid left and side assignment).

Why is this, what am i doing wrong? Thanks,

```
$('#image img').each(function() {
var img_path =  $($(this))[0].src;
var img = $('<img />').attr({ 'src': img_path }); 
$(this) = img;

      $($(this)).resizecrop({
      width:width,
      height:height,
      vertical:"top"
    });  
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't the jquery selector be just `$('img')` ?  Not sure if thats the problem though.

Comment: `$(this)` is not a variable you can assign to; it is an expression returning a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets clear some *misunderstandings* that you seem to have..

- `$($(this))` is the same as `$(this)`
- `$(this)[0]` when `this` is an DOM element is the same as `this`
- you cannot assign a value to a jquery object in order to replace the referenced DOM element, so the `$(this) = img` does not work (*it is what throws that error you mention*)

---

Now, the plugin you use (http://code.google.com/p/resize-crop/) wraps the targeted element in another in order to do its thing..

You will have to unwrap the element, and clear its style for the re-applying of the plugin to work. Also the plugin works as well with a set of element, not only for single elements so you do not have to use `.each()` to run the plugin for each image..

```
$('#image img').unwrap().removeAttr('style').resizecrop({
        width:width,
        height:height,
        vertical:"top"
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to reassign `img` anywhere. It is a JQuery object already so just use it:

```
$('#image img').each(function() {
var img_path =  $($(this))[0].src;
var img = $('<img />').attr({ 'src': img_path }); 
img.resizecrop({
      width:width,
      height:height,
      vertical:"top"
    });  
});
```